# Exchanging huge file trees between disks

Tags: ubuntu, files, rsync, disk-usage

I have two 1TB disks and a huge file tree on each.  Each takes up about 85% of their disk.  I want to swap/exchange the trees between disks.  The only spare (USB) disk that big I have is nearly full.  One problem is that I must split the time to do this.  If I had lots of spare space I would use `rsync` to copy the files and resume that in the next time slot.  **How can I exchange the huge file trees between the disks.**  The host is running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.  The OS is on one of the disks.

*Edit:*

Swapping the drives is not an option because I want to change the relationship between the data being exchanged and the OS.

Comment: What are the specific circumstances in your situation that prevent you from simply exchanging the two drives?